# Amazon rds MySql -> concurrent connections deadlocks

Tags: mysql, deadlock, amazon-rds

I normally hang around in StackOverflow but I think this issue is better suited here.

I've built an application in C#.NET that uses MySql as a database.
My application inserts and updates data in the database in a using the Parallel API (so multithreaded). For reference, the queries that are being fired multithreaded would look like:

```
Update User set IsActive = 1 where UserID = 1 --each thread updates a different user id
```

This has always worked on servers that I manage and development machines.

We recently migrated the MySql database to Amazon RDS, however. Since then, if I run this query multithreaded (even with as low as two concurrent threads), it throws an exception:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Any experience with this issue? Are there some settings in Amazon RDS which are configured differently from a default MySql installation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE User.  I am assuming UserID is the primary key here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in the meantime:

It has to do with the MySql version - the newest MySql version has a number of improvements in the concurrency area which, unfortunately, I could not use at the moment. Probably, if it is configured properly, it will work very good but for me reverting to a older version fixed it.

Comment: What version(s) are you pointing to?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no: I can't think of a difference from MySQL defaults that would cause this.

The longer answer is that it is possible to reduce some locking with READ-COMMITTED as the isolation level + Row-based Replication. To which RDS does not support switching to Row-based Replication :(

Whether or not this reduction in locking will help you depends on your schema.  See [my blog post here under "Write scalability of certain statements"](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/09/04/row-based-replication.html).